# Is using local db a good way to reduce data read/writes from Cloud Db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, local-storage

I am using Cloud Firestore in a React Native app and I am trying to reduce the read/writes operations to a minimum. I just thought of using a local DB so that all data fetched from the cloud are saved in the local storage but I would add a snapshot listener to listen for changes whenever the user starts the app.

Is this a good approach for what I am aiming? If not, why? And if yes, do you have any suggestion related to its implementation?

Comment: Opinions and recommendations for offsite products and libraries are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DougStevenson recommendation  was the last thing, the first was the opinion of others over local DB for cloud read/writes reduction

Comment: Both would be off topic. Consider instead posting to a discussion group, such as Reddit.

Comment: @DougStevenson isnt this the place where we can ask others for solutions to our problems?

Comment: It's for programming questions. Do you have code to share that isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson what I am asking IS a programming topic!

Comment: To be fair, it's a system design question, and there's not enough information here to give a "correct" answer. We don't know how you intend to measure "good". What is the specific use case you're trying to address or optimize? Are you intending to benchmark your solution? How? Are you running into any specific problems with the code you've written so far?

Comment: It might be helpful to read this in order to ask a more specific question that isn't so broad or seeking opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel compelled to point out that the other (currently accepted) answer here is flat out incorrect, or at least misleading for a few reasons.

First, Firestore doesn't use HTTP, and the results of queries are never going to be maintained by your typical browser cache. The claims the answer makes about HTTP caching semantics simply do not apply.

Second, the Firestore SDK uses an internal cache, which is enabled by default on Android and iOS, because its sense of cache is **almost always** going to benefit the end user.  Web applications would do well to enable this cache as well.  It requires one line of code.  This cache will be queried when the client is offline, an can be queried directly if cached results are desired.

Third, adding an additional layer of cache or persistence is actually very necessary for applications that must be fully usable offline.  Firestore was not designed to be use fully offline, so having a local-first option is necessary for some applications.  The additional cache can be synchronized with Firebase as a sort of cloud backup.

All told, the question is technically too broad for Stack Overflow, and it requires conversation to understand if it's worthwhile to enable Firstore's cache, or add an additional cache on top of that.  But it's not patently false that client caching is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks again Doug! I tried to query once like this firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().... but it didnt work, it just didn't query anything and kept loading. However I did not dig deeper into that, I might do it later. Is this enablePersistence() a a good way to persist user authentication so that the user dont have to login everytime?

Comment: Authentication is a completely different matter, and auth SDK automatically persists signins.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good approach.

Caching data is generally a good idea, however implementing this at the DBMS tier will involve writing a lot of code to implement a caching mechanism you have yet to define. The reason it's a bad idea is because JavaScript running on a client already has access to a data tier with very well defined caching semantics already implemented in the the runtime environment - http

Comment: How are you certain about this answer? Firestore client SDKs actually maintain a local cache of data from the server.  If it's such a terrible idea, why do you think it offers an internal cache enabled by default?  There are even reasons to maintain another cache on top of that, but that's not always a good idea.  It's highly dependent on the specific needs of the app, which we don't know here.

Comment: The documentation for the offline cache is here.  I suggest taking a look to see what Firebase offer, and get an idea about use cases for local caches of cloud data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline